# resultMap in mybatis , I need to pass a List of Strings as return type. How to do this in the mapper file

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

```
<select id="getXXX" parameterType="java.util.List" resultMap="?">
</select>
```

In the above select query in my mapper file I need to get the resultMap as a List of Strings. How to implement as default Collection cannot be given directly.

I tried using a plain POJO class with a String variable or a List of String variable but it didnt work out.

Comment: Why do you need to use `resultMap`? If your goal is to get `List<String>` from the statement, you should specify `resultType="string"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get collection of Integers use the following for example:

```
<select id="getXXX" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
</select>
```

If you need to get collection of entities:

```
<select id="getXXX" resultType="com.domain.YourEntity">
</select>
```